# Coupon code always returns error

Tags: coupon, coupon-codes

I have a Magento installation and when I apply a coupon it says.

> Discount code "XXXXXX" is not valid.

[image]

I've cleared cache, disabled cache, tried to re-index all data but still the issue is there. The log file is also empty.

Is there a way to figure out why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [this extension](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_PromoCodeMessages) which changes the error message so that it tells you why the discount could not be applied.

My guess would be something in the "**conditions**" tab that did not match, since I cannot see a problem with the configuration that you show.